# Change text between <option=class>...</option>

Tags: html, css, html-select

I have this code:

```html
<select class="cc-product-variant-selectbox j-product__variants" data-action="changeVariant">
  <option class="j-product__variants__item" value="0" data-params="{&quot;price&quot;:158,&quot;priceFormatted&quot;:&quot;158,00 \u20ac&quot;,&quot;oldPriceFormatted&quot;:&quot;0,00 \u20ac&quot;,&quot;basicPrice&quot;:0,&quot;basicPriceFormatted&quot;:&quot;0,00 \u20ac&quot;,&quot;basicPriceUnit&quot;:&quot;&amp;nbsp;&quot;,&quot;oldPrice&quot;:0,&quot;availability&quot;:1,&quot;availabilityText&quot;:&quot;disponibile&quot;,&quot;delivery&quot;:2,&quot;pool&quot;:&quot;Infinity&quot;,&quot;weightFormatted&quot;:&quot;0,1 kg&quot;,&quot;weight&quot;:0.1}"
          title="1 metro     158,00 €" content="1 metro" selected="selected">
    1 metro 158,00 €</option>
```

I would change the dropbox text "1 metro  158,00 €" (that is between `<option>..</option>`) in "1 metro" so without the price. I tried in css this code:

`.j-product__variants__item"{content:"1 metro";}`

but it doesn't works.
How can I resolve it?

Comment: `content` is only available for pseudo elements `::before` and `::after`. There is no way to solve your problem with CSS.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, can't you just deletece `158,00 €` from your `<option>` text? (Básicamente borra el texto entre tus `<option>`. No se te entiende muy bien)

Comment: thank you for your answer, is it helpful using javascript?

Comment: Javascript is your only chance here.

Comment: that's what i was about to say, it will be almost impossible in CSS without tricky tricks, but perfectly doable in javascript. Or if you have control over the file that generates the HTML, it would be even better.

Comment: @JohnnyKutnowski yes I can't. I'm using a Jimdo site and I'm modifying some div with css, I tried to modify this element but I did not succeeded

Comment: @Kaddath I searched for Javascript that could works, but I cannot edit html directly because I use a platform like Jimdo where I have my website and I can only work on css code.

Comment: @connexo I searched for Javascript that could works, but I cannot edit html directly because I use a platform like Jimdo where I have my website and I can only work on css code.

Comment: it says here [https://support.jimdo.com/design/edit-head/](https://support.jimdo.com/design/edit-head/) that you can add javascript same way as styles in the head, give it a try, it should work

Comment: @Kaddath Yes, I tried some javascripts styled in the head but they don't works

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty Javascript solution:

```js
// document.querySelectorAll('.j-product__variants__item')[0].innerHTML = document.querySelectorAll('.j-product__variants__item')[0].textContent.replace('158,00 €','');
```

```html
<body onload="document.querySelectorAll('.j-product__variants__item')[0].innerHTML = document.querySelectorAll('.j-product__variants__item')[0].textContent.replace('158,00 €','');">
  <select class="cc-product-variant-selectbox j-product__variants" data-action="changeVariant">
    <option class="j-product__variants__item" value="0" data-params="{&quot;price&quot;:158,&quot;priceFormatted&quot;:&quot;158,00 \u20ac&quot;,&quot;oldPriceFormatted&quot;:&quot;0,00 \u20ac&quot;,&quot;basicPrice&quot;:0,&quot;basicPriceFormatted&quot;:&quot;0,00 \u20ac&quot;,&quot;basicPriceUnit&quot;:&quot;&amp;nbsp;&quot;,&quot;oldPrice&quot;:0,&quot;availability&quot;:1,&quot;availabilityText&quot;:&quot;disponibile&quot;,&quot;delivery&quot;:2,&quot;pool&quot;:&quot;Infinity&quot;,&quot;weightFormatted&quot;:&quot;0,1 kg&quot;,&quot;weight&quot;:0.1}"
    title="1 metro     158,00 €" content="1 metro" selected="selected">
      1 metro 158,00 €</option>
  </select>
</body>
```

Comment: I embedded the javascript you suggested but how do I connect the function on my css sheet? I have to put <body onload="document.querySelectorAll('.j-product__variants__item')[0].innerHTML = document.querySelectorAll('.j-product__variants__item')[0].textContent.replace('158,00 €','');"> in <style type="text/css">?

Comment: No, you have to put it on the body tag of the HTML. Or in a `<script>` tag at the bottom of the page. `<style>` is for CSS only. From https://support.jimdo.com/design/edit-head/ : *In the default text field, you can enter <script>, <style>, <meta>, <base>, and <link> tags.*

Comment: Thank you for you support, I can only add an HTML widget on my website. I have added that script <body onload>... into this widget and document.querySelectorAll... using <script> in CSS sheet. It works but I cannot delete that main dropdown menu already created using Jimdo because I can't manage real HTML (not widget) since I have no permission :( I can only modify layout aspects of HTML with CSS in the head sheet and introducing some HTML widgets but deleting nothing.
I hoped there was a solution with js without managing HTML but only recalling the div already existing into the css sheet :(

Comment: put `<script>window.onload = function() { document.querySelectorAll('.j-product__variants__item')[0].innerHTML = document.querySelectorAll('.j-product__variants__item')[0].textContent.replace('158,00 €',''); };</script>` in that head block.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works! But why does it take time to load? It takes a second or two before loading the replaced content

Comment: Because the script only executes once all asets for the page have been loaded. This is necessary to make sure the DOM element you're trying to access is available by the time the script runs. If this solved your problem, you might want to consider an upvote on top of marking this as the answer.

Comment: Thank you! This is what appeared when I tried to vote: " Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. "

Comment: The more important part is marking the correct answer.